# PNACL pthread_mutex_lock calls get stuck at some places

Tags: google-nativeclient

I am trying to convert some async PPAPI calls to sync. After CallOnMainThread call, the calling thread is blocked using the below mentioned Block() function and after the callback function is called the thread is resumed after the callback using the below mentioned Resume() function.

```
void MyClass::Block()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&done_mutex);
    while (!is_done) {
        printf("Blocking...\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&done_cond, &done_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&done_mutex);
}

void MyClass::Resume()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&done_mutex);
    is_done = true;
    printf("Resuming...\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&done_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&done_mutex);
}
```

Here, done_mutex and done_cond are attributes of MyClass and are initialized as pthread_mutex_init(&done_mutex, NULL) and pthread_cond_init(&done_cond, NULL), respectively.

What I am unable to get is that this mechanism is failing when called from some specific points in my code, in which case, pthread_mutex_lock(&done_mutex) call gets stuck indefinitely and the page becomes unresponsive.

I tried to print some of the attributes of the pthread_mutex_t structure (shown below) and found some irregularity.

mutex_type = 0 owner_thread_id = 0x7d01, recursion_counter = 1, mutex_handle = 94

It seems that the value of owner_thread_id attribute of is garbage, because at points where it works fine, the values are 4 bytes wide (for eg, 0x101594c8) and also, the same value comes up over and over again. I cannot make out how it is getting these garbage values, and that too only at some specific points in the code.

I also tried to use done_mutex as a pthread_mutex_t pointer in MyClass, allocate it on heap and then use pthread_mutex_init as follows.

```
done_mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
int ret = pthread_mutex_init(done_mutex, NULL);
```

What's really weird is that, done_mutex is getting reset to NULL after the pthread_mutex_init call when called from these specific points in the code, else it works as expected.

I am compiling my code with pepper21 toolchain and trying it on pepper_canary. Can that lead to such issues?

I have been stuck at it for a long time now. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this problem still happen for you with the newest PNaCl & Chrome?